# separate member and guest template content in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to have mixes member and guest templates.
The main difference would be the menu of the page.  In some languages i've worked with you can add prefixes to templates to get it to switch out the whole templates for the other version.
ex:
base.guest.html
base.member.html

In Django the only way i've seen any thing related to this is this code i found in the documents:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # Do something for authenticated users.
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
```

Is this the base way to do this in Django?  or is there something else that i'm missing.

For most of my pages this would work out ok but wasn't sure if there was a better way to switch content based on authenticated state.

Comment: if the else is repeated into many views, you can create a custom middleware to see if the users are logged in

Comment: If you use `RequestContext` to render your templates you get `user` variable in your template. Then you can use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and write appropriate html in template.

Comment: yea, i'm aware of the {% if user.is_authenticated %} option.  But i guess i was looking for a way to do {% extends "base.html" %} and have it auto include a version depending on authenticated state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `extend` in this case, instead you `include`. The `base.html` should authentication-agnostic.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% include 'member.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'guest.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to, you can do have the if-statement also in your view, and pass the name of the template-to-be-included to the main template. For more info see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include